# tufte-book figure* broken with floatrow

Tags: graphics, tufte, floatrow

I would like to include a full-width figure in a document prepared with the `tufte-book` class.

I've found that using the `floatrow` package, along with using the `setkeys` option of `graphicx`, breaks the `tufte-book` `figure*` float.

---

MWE

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}

\begin{document}

Here is a figure that I would like to be fullwidth.

\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

---

Actual output
[image]

---

Desired output
[image]

Comment: I'm not surprised floatrow is incompatible with tufte, as both redefine the figure and figure* environments.  If you comment it out, the MWE works fine.

Comment: Yes. Although not shown in the MWE, I use `floatrow` elsewhere to declare a new floating enviornment. Ideally, I'd be able to keep using `floatrow` to declare my floating environment, but without `floatrow` impacting tufte's figure*

Comment: You can use the newfloat and float packages to create new floating environments without changing figure and table (just don't use the package options with float).

Comment: Thanks, if no other solutions are forthcoming, I will likely resort to this solution.

Comment: The `newfloat` package seems to be adapted to the `tufte` document class, at least this is what I just found in the dtx file: "If the \class{tufte} document class is loaded, |\@tufte@float| and |\end@tufte@float| will be used instead of |\@float|, |\end@float|, |\@dblfloat|, and |\end@dblfloat|."

(But I couldn't find anything about `tufte` in the `newfloat` manual.)

Answer (score 3):

It works for me both with pdf latex and lualatex

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

Here is a figure that I would like to be fullwidth.

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

It does not solve the conflict but is a workaround. The tufte class it is not maintained since 2015.

[image: output]